# How to create a dialog in a iPhone application?

Tags: iphone, uialertview

How to create a dialog in a iPhone application?

Comment: What do you mean by dialog?  The question's not very clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`UIAlertView` is probably the class you're looking for.

Comment: thank you very much.
I want to add label、button and so on on the dialog，the ＵIAlertView can realize it？

Comment: Read the documentation for `UIAlertView`. Most of your questions about the class are covered by Apple's docs.